# Facebook rate limit not reached

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm working on an  web app in which a user can access and publish content on their wall , storing in my database the publication ID .

On the other hand I have a C# console application that for each one of the publications stored in the database makes a request of its likes.

Both apps works perfectly , but I have not reached the limit of 200 calls per user and hour, although I have only five test users and I have made more than 3,000 calls in less than an hour.

The call I'm making is:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/[PostID]/likes?summary=true&access_token=[UserAccessToken];
```

Why I have not reached the rate limit?

NOTE: The UserAccesToken is long lived type and is stored in my database when users logged on.

Another question. Is there any limit difference between the app and the user access token for make this request?

Comment: Are you sure your app has only a single user? the per-app limits are based on user count as well as being per-user : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/rate-limiting

Comment: I have currently 6 users using my app acording to the Facebook developers dashboard and five of them are test users.

As I have understood reading the documentation and your comment, I would be able to make queries using the application token or the user token and I will get the same rate limit. Does this mean that if I have a million users I will be able to make 200 million calls using both tokens?

Comment: No, there are also per-user limits - if you're trying to work around the limits to engage in scraping data in bulk on behalf of few users, this won't work out long term; you should access a user's data (or data for a user) using that user's token

Comment: Ok, all clear. Then why i have not reached the rate limit if one of my test users has 1300 posts and i'm requesting the likes count for each one of them?